# Openssl command to generate a key pair with a common modulus value (N)

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rsa

I know RSA has a common modulus problem (basically when we select a common value for N for multiple entities in an organization, we known the prime factors p and q). Using the other persons pulic key, we can find the private key since we know the prime factos. What is the openssl command to generate a pair with a common value of N?

Comment: I am afraid that openssl does not provide such functionality.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.